# Find partial sum of 'X' numbers in array in c

Tags: c

can you help me with code which returns partial sum of 'X' numbers in array in c?

Complete :

```
    int arr_sum( int arr[], int n )//Recursive sum of array
     { 
      if (n < 0) //base case:
      {

        return arr[0];
      }
      else
      {
        return arr[n] + arr_sum(arr, n-1);
      }
    }
    void sum_till_last (int *ar,int si )
    {

        **int sum,i;// the problem some where here
        ar=(int*) malloc(si*sizeof(int));

        for (i=0; i<si;i++)
        {

            sum=arr_sum(ar,i);
            ar [i]=sum;
        }
        free (ar);**
    }


 void main ()
{
    int i;
    int a [5];
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
      scanf_s("%d", &a[i]);

    sum_till_last(a,5);
    printf("%d\n",a[5]);
}
```

\i want to create new array with this this legality:
My input :

4
13
23
21
11

The output should be (without brackets or commas):

4 
17
40
61 
72

Comment: When you allocate memory in `sum_till_last` that memory is not initialized, its contents is *indeterminate*. You can't use it (which you do when you call `arr_sum`) until you have initialized the memory. I also wonder why you pass `ar` as an argument to `sum_till_last` since it is used as a local variable?

Comment: What is your question now? What happens when you run it in a debugger?

Comment: Also please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us, including how you *actually* call the `sum_till_last` function. Also please  [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). And while you're editing your question then show us the input you use, and the expected and actual output.

Comment: Lastly, I assume that the base case should be `n <= 0`? Otherwise when `n` is zero you will return `arr[0] + arr_sum(arr, -1)`, effectively `arr[0] + arr[0]`.

Comment: For `n<0` you should use 0 in `arr_sum` and you should not store your result in `arr[i]` in `main` as it spoils your array for the next execution of your loop.

Comment: Can't `arr_sum` simply be: `return (n > 0) ? *arr + arr_sum(arr+1,n-1) : 0;` , assuming your intention was recursion (that no one would ever actually do outside of academia?)

Answer (score 2):

Now when we can see the full code, it's quite obvious that the problem is in the `sum_till_last` function where you overwrite the pointer you pass to the function with some new and uninitialized memory you allocate.

Drop the allocation (and the call to `free` of course). And fix the logical bug in `arr_sum` that causes you to get `arr[0] + arr[0]` when `i` is zero.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
   int in_arr[5] = {4,13,23,21,11};
   int out_arr[5];
   int p_sum =0;
   int i;

   for ( i=0;i<5;i++){
      out_arr[i] = in_arr[i]+p_sum;
      p_sum=p_sum+in_arr[i];
   }

   for (i=0;i<5;i++){
      printf("%d", out_arr[i] );
   }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just made it simple so it´s easy to understand :)
I´m assuming "n" is always equal or less then array element number. Then you just print the SUM.

```
  #include  <stdio.h>

     int arr_sum( int arr[], int n ){
         int i=0,SUM=0;   
         for(; i < n;i++){
           SUM= SUM+ arr[i];
           printf("%d ",SUM);
         }  
    }

     int main(void) {
         int array[] = {4, 13, 23, 21, 11};
         arr_sum(array,5);
         return 0;
     }
```

Comment: You can't use `sizeof(arr)` to get the size of an array passed as function argument. The size will only be size of a pointer. You need to pass the number of elements as extra parameter

Comment: you are right :) sorry i don´t use C for long. i will change it

Comment: you are right, in this new implementation it´s actually quite simple :)

Answer (score 0):

Fix according to your policy

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int arr_sum(int arr[], int n){
    if (n == 0){//Change to this
        return arr[0];
    } else {
        return arr[n] + arr_sum(arr, n-1);
    }
}

void sum_till_last(int *ar, int si){
    int sum,i;
    int *temp = malloc(si * sizeof(int));//variable name ar is shadowing parameter name ar.

    for(i = 0; i < si; i++){
        temp[i] = arr_sum(ar, i);
        if(i)
            putchar(' ');
        printf("%d", temp[i]);//need print out :D
    }
    free(temp);
}

int main(void){
    int i, a[5];

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        scanf_s("%d", &a[i]);

    sum_till_last(a, 5);
    //printf("%d\n",a[5]);<-- this print only one element. and It's out of bounds element XD 
}
```

Comment: Thank you. its very nice that you also put explanation. its very helped

Comment: what did error mean  >>> ''IntelliSense: a value of type "void *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "int *"

Comment: @AlexZelentsov You use C++ as C. In that case Change to `int *temp = (int*)malloc(si * sizeof(int));`. But C does not need such a cast.